# Add key on each json object in Promise

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following `Promise` and `Promise.all` which works and it returns a json object. However, I want to add a key for each return object.

as of now, it returns something

```
 [value: {school object}, value:{students object}, value:{classroom object}]
```

**desired output:**

```
 ["schools": {school object }, {students object} , {classroom object} ]
```

**Current Implementation:**

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const school = getschool (webHost, dataSource, req);
    const classRooms = getClassRooms(webHost, dataSource, req);
    const students = getstudents (webHost,dataSource, req);
    Promise.all([school ,classRooms,students ]).then((res) => {
            resolve(res);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            logger.error(`${error}`);
            reject(error);
        });
});
```

**classroom**

```
{
    "metadata": "metadata",
    "value": [
        {
            "class_id": "171717",
            "teacher_name": "Science"
        }
    ]
}
```

**School object**

```
{
    "metadata": "metadata",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "2345354",
            "schoolName": "Memorial High School"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Student json**

```
{
    "metadata": "metadata",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "studentName": "Beck"
        },
        {
            "id": "5678",
            "studentName": "Jeck"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[
   {
      "class_id":"171717",
      "teacher_name":"Science",
      "id":"2345354",
      "schoolName":"Memorial High School",
      "Students":[
         {
            "id":"1234",
            "studentName":"Beck"
         },
         {
            "id":"5678",
            "studentName":"Jeck"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to merge the objects to make one unified object of custom type, here is what you want to do:

```js
res => resolve(
 {
  ...res[1].value[0],
  ...res[0].value[0],
  Students: res[2].value
 }
)
```

The [`...` is called spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It "explodes" the objects and arrays. What we want here is get the internals of `classRooms.value[0]` merge them with `school.value[0]` object's internals, and then, add another attribute at the same level with key as `Students` which is a *not-exploded* array specified by `student.value`.

Here I have created a small [TS Playground Example](https://tsplay.dev/nWPrEN) for you to play with the syntax and modify the output the way you may seem fit.

If you run it, it prints the desired output:

```json
{
  "class_id": "171717",
  "teacher_name": "Science",
  "id": "2345354",
  "schoolName": "Memorial High School",
  "Students": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "studentName": "Beck"
    },
    {
      "id": "5678",
      "studentName": "Jeck"
    }
  ]
}
```

-- ORIGINAL ANSWER --
[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns a promise of resolved objects in an array. So, the `.then` takes the parameter that's an array of resolved objects in the same order. That means your `res` parameter is an array of school object, students object, and classroom object in that order. you can do the following to "zip" them up.

```ts
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const school = getschool (webHost, dataSource, req);
    const classRooms = getClassRooms(webHost, dataSource, req);
    const students = getstudents (webHost,dataSource, req);
    Promise.all([school ,classRooms,students ]).then((res) => {
            resolve({"schools": res[0], "classRooms" : res[1], "students": res[2]});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            logger.error(`${error}`);
            reject(error);
        });
});
```

or even better,

```
.then(([schools, classRooms, students]) => {
  resolve({schools, classRooms, students});
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nishat. I have one quick follow up question. If I want to form a json object with  resolve({"schools": res[0],  res[1], res[2]}); is not possible? I only want to add a key for one of them?

Comment: The JSON you mentioned is not a valid object. JSON must have key-value pair. The shape of JSON object is completely up to you. You can for example do this: `resolve({schools: res})` in this case you will get an object with one key named `schools` and the value of this key is the `res` array. Or, `resolve({schools: {school: res[0], classRooms: res[1], students: res[2]}})` this has one top level key as schools and the `res` array is packed as an object created from the res array

Comment: Nishant, I have updated my question accordingly. Would you mind to check it?

Comment: Ah, you want to merge it. Let me update the answer.